# Need advice on how to compare, and remove occurrences of, one string from another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've got a problem that's been driving me kind of nuts. I have to write a function that takes two strings, stringA and stringB, and using stringA remove all instances of stringA from stringB. The resulting string C should have no instances of A in it and zero white space.

Test cases would be:

```
stringA = 'ab';  
stringB = 'aabb';
stringC = ' ';
```

or

```
stringA = ')(';  
stringB = '((()))'  
stringC = stringB;
```

So far my general approach has been to start with two prompts stored in variables that collect the strings. .replace() is run on both in order to remove any white space.

The closest I've gotten was two for loops, one for stringA with string B nested inside, and testing the indices against eachother for matches. If it's not a match, pushing it to stringC. But my problem is, its not really removing the instances of stringA only if the two indices in question happen to match at that time.

I've searched around here quite a bit and came up with .filter() or .replace() but I'm not having any luck/insight on how exactly to use those. Any advice would be super helpful, I feel like I've hit a wall. [Here's a link to my code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zzddew8/)

Thanks, everyone.

**UPDATE**

You guys are amazing. :) I don't want to just steal an answer and pass it in, but you've all given me a wealth of things to look into and understand so that when I DO solve it, I understand the why and not just the what. Thanks so much for the fast answers, help, and guidance.

Comment: oh crap. thanks man, I fixed it. I forgot the publish thing.

Comment: You've hit a wall? What have you tried with .filter or .replace?

Comment: So if stringA is '1' and stringB is '12341', then stringC should be '234'? Or do you want to relpace every single character from stringA in stringB (as per your first example)?

Comment: You did not actually used any replace or filter :) Perhaps, you just want [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/0zzddew8/1/).

Comment: no, I haven't, I've tried it but I can't get it to work. I think my main problem is maybe not understanding the question. "removing all occurances of stringA from stringB" does that mean just removing duplicate characters? or duplicate words?

with .filter() I tried writing a filter that would test whether stringB's index matched stringA's, ditto with replace(). I've also tried while loops (oh god I hate while loops) and do while.

Comment: Unsure exactly the rules of the game, is this accurate: if stringA is 'ab', and stringB is 'aaaaabbbbb' .... do we remove 'ab' each time such that
on pass 1: 'aaaabbbb'
on pass 2: 'aaabbb'
on pass 3: aabb'
on pass 4: 'ab'
on pass 5: ''
?

Comment: If you need to repeatedly replace until no match is found, use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vu8n3y6q/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, using recursion:

https://jsfiddle.net/iamnotsam/ytvujc9a/ (<-- is commented)

```js
// removes all instances of a string s1 from another string s2
var removeAllSubstrings = function(s1, s2, s3) {
    if (s2 === '' || s2 === s3) { return s2; }    
    return removeAllSubstrings(s1, s2.replace(s1,''), s2);
}

var sa = 'ab',
    sb = 'doaaabbbaabbababne';

// Put the final string on the screen
document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = removeAllSubstrings(sa, sb);
```

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<title>challange</title>

<body>
 <h1 id="t">String Remover</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```js
var stringA = 'ab',
    stringB = 'aabb';

do {
    var before = stringB;
    stringB = stringB.replace(stringA, '');
} while (stringB != before);

alert(stringB);
```

Comment: this is so simple. but can you explain a little bit what's going on in that loop?  

`set before to stringB`  
   
`then set stringB to stringB.replace(stringA, '')`     <-- that replaces any instance of stringA with a space?  

      
` while stringB is not equal to before` before is the original stringB
*I've tried a dozen times to format this so it looks neater but to no avail. sorry :( *

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform global search and replace plus one additional replace for remaining string.

```
var stringA = 'ab';  
var stringB = 'aabb';
var stringC;

var regex  = new RegExp(stringA, "g");

stringC = stringB.replace(regex, "").replace(regex, "");
console.log(stringC);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all occurrences of a Word A inside Word B *until no match is found*, in loops, you can use:

```js
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}

var stringRemover = function() {

    var stringA = "()";
    var stringB = 'a((()))b';
    var stringC = stringB;
    var rx = RegExp(escapeRegExp(stringA), "g");
    while (stringC.indexOf(stringA) > -1) {
     stringC = stringC.replace(rx, "");
    }
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = stringC;
}
stringRemover();
```

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<title>challange</title>

<body>
 <h1 id="t">String Remover</h1>
</body>
```

It is important to use a regex-based replace to remove all occurrences (with `g` modifier it is global) and check in a loop if Word B still contains Word A. To make a correct dynamic regex, we should use an `escapeRegExp` function.

Comment: I have a lot of reading to do on regex, apparently ! think regex is definitely the way to go (another user used recursion, and I don't know enough about javascript [clearly] to say which one's better but the term 'recursive function' scares the bejesus out of me.) so regex it is. Thank you for the small breakdown and keywords worth looking into.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do not forget to upvote those answers that were helpful to you, and accept the one that works for you best.